# React-Native error "RN Sketch not found in the UIManager"

Tags: ios, react-native, native, react-native-ios, react-native-sketch-canvas

I'm trying to build a react-native sketch project and I believe I've installed all the required libraries for it to work on my machine, but for some reason I keep on getting this error, which I'm not sure how to resolve.
Also, I wasn't sure what it meant by the linking of the react native to react native sketch, when installing the react-native sketch.

`react-native link react-native-sketch`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sharing your code will help debug the issue.  But if the code is right then see below for installation.

So when installing this package, it is not enough to just install it.  You must link to React Native. So do;

```
npm i -S react-native-sketch
```

That will install it. Now to make React Native 'aware' of this newly installed package, link it as follows;

```
react-native link react-native-sketch
```

This is just putting it in simple terms for understanding.
You should get a success message for both of the above - if an error occurs while running any of the above command lines, then it did not succeed and you'll get the error above.

If developing on IOS, don't forget to pod install and re run the project after installing the package!

CD to IOS directory - type 'pod install' and ENTER. Re Run the project.